# LOAD DATA INFILE and Double Quotes

Tags: mysql, csv

When I export table to csv, fputcsv adds double quotes to values with space, for example:

```
day|night|summer|winter
something|123|something|"Bauer Jack"
foo|bla|5|dooper
```

I figured out I cannot avoid that.

The problem becomes when I try to import this csv with LOAD DATA INFILE, it does not import a line that contains double quotes. So line with "Bauer Jack" example is not imported into mysql.

```
$query = <<<eof
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$filename' INTO TABLE `table_name`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
eof;
```

Can you suggest a solution? Why is line with double quotes not imported?

Everything works fine when I remove double quotes from csv file.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY clause first.

```
$query = <<<eof
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$filename' INTO TABLE `table_name`
FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' TERMINATED BY '|' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
eof;
```

Comment: I tried but using single or double quotes as a enclosed character it always failed when importing. I ended up using ^ and then it worked as intended.